# Encoding issue with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, encoding, mysql-workbench

I have database in `UTF-8` (`utf8_general_ci`) enconding in `phpMyAdmin`. I export it as `CSV` file to another computer where `MySQL Workbench` is installed. The encoding problem is only with cyrillic characters when I import it to the `MySQL Workbench`. It displays as garbage:

```
Р—РІС–С‚Рё
Р—РµР»РµРЅР° РєР°СЂС‚Р°
```

I have checked the schema encoding in `MySQL Workbench`:

**Default collation:** utf8mb3_general_ci

**Default characterset:** utf8mb3

When I try to alter the schema and set `UTF-8/utf8_general_ci` in the `MySQL Workbench` it reports as:

```
Apply changes to pess   Changes applied
```

But this schema is still in `utf8mb3_general_ci/utf8mb3`. The question is how can I change the encoding to `UTF-8/utf8_general_ci` in `MySQL Workbench`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use utf8mb4 in the current version of MySQL 5.7 or 8.0.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html

> **Note**
>
> Historically, MySQL has used utf8 as an alias for utf8mb3; beginning
> with MySQL 8.0.28, utf8mb3 is used exclusively in the output of SHOW
> statements and in Information Schema tables when this character set is
> meant.
>
> At some point in the future utf8 is expected to become a reference to
> utf8mb4. To avoid ambiguity about the meaning of utf8, consider
> specifying utf8mb4 explicitly for character set references instead of
> utf8.
>
> You should also be aware that the utf8mb3 character set is deprecated
> and you should expect it to be removed in a future MySQL release.
> Please use utf8mb4 instead.

Comment: Ok. So, you mean I should change the database encoding to `utf8mb4` in `phpMyAdmin` and `MySQL Workbench` or only in `MySQL Workbench`? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated the encoding to utf8mb4 (utf8mb4_general_ci) in `phpMyAdmin` and `MySQL Workbench` but this encoding issue is still exists. The cyrilic characters displays as: РџСЂРѕРјРѕРєРѕРґРё when I import table to MySQL Workbench from phpMyAdmin.
What could be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: Could it be the issue with different database types? For example, on phpMyAdmin it's `MyISAM`. On MySQL Workbench it's `InnoDB`?

Comment: I don't know. I never use MyISAM, but as far as I recall, it handles character sets the same as InnoDB. Also I never use phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench. I don't even have them installed. I don't want to use a GUI that interferes with defaults or tries to second-guess my intentions.

Comment: Ok. I have found what causes such issue. So, this issue was related to the encoding of `CSV` file. When I export table from `phpMyAdmin` as `Windows-1251` with cyrilic characters and try to import it to `MySQL Workbench` as `UTF-8` it displays the cyrilic characters correctly. It works for `MyISAM` and `InnoDB` engines.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Р—РІС–С‚Рё` supposed to be saying `Звіти` ?  If so, it looks like you got 'Mojibake' involving cp1251 instead of utf8.

See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) .  In particular see the tip on fetching `SELECT HEX(col) ...` -- This may help discover further whether the data was stored incorrectly or being fetched incorrectly.  Or maybe something worse, like 'double-encoding'.

The other string may be `Зелена карта`?

(MyISAM versus InnoDB is not relevent in character set encoding problems.)